how to replace a string with a variable?
I am trying to write a script containing a loop that enters a series of directories containing the same file, to replace a text string in a file with a variable that matches the directory's name.
The variable is $i=3,4,5 and the file name is FILE
what i have wrote so far:
for i in ./*z  
do
  cd $i  
  if  
    grep -q 'DZ' FILE
  then
    sed -i 's/DZ/$iZ/g' FILE
  fi  
  cd ..  
done

Instead of DZ I get $iZ without the variable change.
how can I fix this?

Do you mean DZ changes to literal $iZ? That's unlikely because of the double quotes.

Ditto. And see this. Note your ${i} will be like ./1z or so, with the dot and the slash (that will break the sed command); you probably don't want exactly this in the file.

you're right, my bad. it a typo. I meant to write apostrophe. corrected the format.

That's expected. Single quotes don't expand variables, and sed doesn't understand shell variables.

What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?

Assuming that you want all occurrences of DZ in the ./fooz/FILE file to be replaced with fooZ, on a GNU system, that could be:
grep -lZe DZ -- *z/FILE |
  xargs -r0 perl -pi -e '
    my $repl = "${1}Z" if $ARGV =~ m{(.*?)z/};
    s/DZ/$repl/g' --


You need to use double quotes " in the sed line, instead of single quotes ', if you want the variable to be expanded. Otherwise the $i remains whithout expansion. Also, since the Z is not part of the variable, you need a separator, for example using the ${i} syntax.
So, your script should be
for i in ./*z  
do
  cd $i  
  if  
    grep -q 'DZ' FILE
  then
    sed -i "s/DZ/${i}Z/g" FILE
  fi  
  cd ..  
done



$iZ will expand to the contents of the iZ shell variable though. Having data expanded into code (here sed code) is also a big security anti-pattern which should be avoided. Also, inherited from the OP's code, note the missing quotes around $i and missing -- in cd $i and the missing check for the success of that operation. It's also better to cd in a subshell rather than using cd .. which is not always guaranteed to get you back to where you started.

This won't work as ${i} will contain a / which will break sed.
